# How to extract files from C++ program and then run one from them

Tags: c++, installation, exec, exe, extract

**I'm writing updater program in C++, i need extract files from them.**
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio.

What I'd like the achieve:

1. User runs exe
2. exe unpacks files
3. exe runs one of extracted files

Can anyone recommend a good solution?

**Thanks!**

Comment: The best solution is to open your favorite text editor, and write the code to do this.

Comment: i dont know how to extract resources from my program

Comment: see http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Zip2Exe, for example

Comment: can i extract resources from C++ program ?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can. You can do pretty much anything from a C++ program. You just have to write the code to do it. `stackoverflow.com` is not a code-writing service with instant gratification. It's for asking specific questions, on technical topics. If you want to learn how to unpack files from an archive, I'm sure there's plenty of reading material that you can search in Google, for software libraries that will let you do that.

Comment: thank you so much !!! kappa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting resources from a file with C++:

[Extract file from resource in Windows module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388134/extract-file-from-resource-in-windows-module)

[Self-Extracting Executable C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927721/self-extracting-executable-c)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4221/Adding-and-extracting-binary-resources

Answer (score 1):

You're writing an updater.

- User runs exe
- exe unpacks files
- exe runs one of extracted files

So your program should:

- Download the patch from the server (use a networking library like *winsock* or something higher-level)
- Unzip the archive (depending on the format in question, there should be libraries for that, like *zlib*)
- Move the new files and overwrite the old ones (use *win32* or something higher-level like *MFC* or *Qt*)